# Possible race condition in Parallel.Foreach

Tags: .net, vb.net, parallel.foreach

I have the following vb.net code and I am not sure if there might be a race condition here or not.

In my tests I did not see evidence for a race condition.

```
Public Class Worker
    Private _List As New List(Of clsTag)
    ' assume that we added tag objects to list defined above ....
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim tagCol As IEnumerable = _List 
        Parallel.ForEach(tagCol.Cast(Of Object)(), Sub(TagObj As clsTag)
            TagObj.CheckLogicValue()
        End Sub)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class clsTag 
    Public Sub CheckLogicValue()
        ...
        glbObject.CalcSomething(Me)
        ...
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class SharedObject
    Public Function CalcSomething(ByRef objTag As clsTag) As Decimal
        ' Do some calculation based on objTag and also modify objTag status here!
    End Function
End Class
```

Where `glbObject` is a global object, and an instance of the `SharedObject` class, and the function `CalcSomething` gets the `TagObj ByRef` and modifies this object. 
Is it safe?

Regarding what `CalcSomething` does:

- It goes over the list of all tags (which is a `_List`) and reads from it (does not make any modifications).
- Based on things that are found on the list some expression is being calculated, this expression neither changes the tag object nor the list

Based on the calculation result (which is also what the function returns) a field of the `tagObject` that was passed `ByRef` is being updated, so it is something like this:

```
Public Class SharedObject
     Public Function CalcSomething(ByRef objTag As clsTag) As Decimal
         ' Do some calculation based on objTag and also modify objTag status here!
         if (...) then
             objTag.ItemBroken = False
         EndIf
     End Function
End Class
```

Comment: The code inside of CalcSomething is important here. We need to know, for example, if it is accessing any state.

Comment: I am afraid that the code is too specific so no one would want to bother to understand it. I will edit my main post and add some information about it

Answer (score 0):

1. If the code in `CalcSomething` modifies (or even uses) some state variables other than what's contained in the passed argument, then you do have a clear cut race condition.
2. Even if you don't access anything other than the argument, if you are changing it, it's still possible to get a race condition, if the same object is used twice in the collection, e.g.

   ```
   Dim _tag = New clsTag With {...}
   _List.Add(_tag);
   _List.Add(_tag);
   ```

Note that a definite answer is not possible unless we know exactly what the code is doing.
If global state is only read from, and you are absolutely sure that that that state will not be changed during the execution of the method, than you should be safe from a global value race condition.
Also, if the `.ItemBroken` (or any other field/property that is set) is not used in the calculation itself, but is only set as a result of some (repeatable) check, you can be reasonably sure that you won't get a race condition.

On the other hand, `Paralel.For` will not magically speed up your processing, and it will make the code harder to understand. Are you sure that a simple, sequential `Foreach` won't be just as fast, while being simpler to understand and debug?

```
For Each TagObj As clsTag In tagCol
    TagObj.CheckLogicValue()
Next
```

Comment: I am trying to improve the performance of a code that I did not write. The original code was a sequential loop that was wrapped inside Synclock, and it took a very long time. I wanted to speed things up by removing the Synclock and adding parallelism. I think that the person who wrote that code was afraid that the collection will be changed by some other threads in the software that access it

Comment: This makes me think, maybe I should keep it sequential, and remove the Synclock. But still I might have a problem if some other thread changes the collection while I iterate it. What is the best approach in this case?

Comment: It depends too much on your actual case. Is change of the collection likely or impossible? A simple locking should not have too much of an adverse impact on the performance anyway. Are you actually locking some global state, that will force other threads to wait? Did you profile the code to see it the bottleneck is actually not in the code itself?

Comment: The lock was on a global variable. After spending some more time, I don't see threads that may change the collection. So I think that it is safe to remove the lock. Now the question that remains is only regarding the risk in converting the sequential loop to a parallel loop